# Bibliography and URLs in references

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, urls

The functions in the end are defined in my `.bst` file. What they do is, when I add the field

```
webpage={http://xxx.xxx.xxx...../}
```

to a bibitem, it displays at the end of the reference in the bibliography the text:

```
... URL: http://xxx.xxx.xxx...../
```

(where the three first dots indicate the rest of the reference: authors, title, journal, etc..)
What I would like is that instead of **showing** the actual url, it became a link of the text *URL*. This way the reference would only show the text *URL* at the end (and **not** the url itself) which I could click and go to that link.

Is this possible?

**FUNCTIONS**

```
ENTRY
  { address
    ...
    webpage
    year
   ...
  }


FUNCTION {format.webpage}
{   
webpage "webpage" bibinfo.check
duplicate$ empty$ 'skip$
{ new.block
  bbl.availableat " \url{" * swap$ *  "}" *
}
if$
}

FUNCTION {bbl.availableat}
{ "URL: " }

FUNCTION {new.block}
{ output.state before.all =
'skip$
{ after.block 'output.state := }
 if$
}

FUNCTION {bibinfo.check}
{ swap$
  duplicate$ missing$
{
  pop$ pop$
  ""
}
{ duplicate$ empty$
    {
      swap$ pop$
    }
    { swap$
      pop$
    }
  if$
}
  if$
}
```

---

## Edit

I tried Mico's suggestion and changed the `webpage`function like so:

```
FUNCTION {format.webpage}
{   
webpage "webpage" bibinfo.check
duplicate$ empty$ 'skip$
{ new.block
      " \href{" * swap$ *  "}{URL}" *
}
if$
}
```

my bibfile contains only one item:

```
@ARTICLE{Dummy2012,
  author = {{Vink}, J.~S. and {Gr{\"a}fener}, G.},
  title = {{The Transition Mass-loss Rate: Calibrating the Role of Line-driven Winds in Massive Star Evolution}},
  journal = {APJL},
  year = {2012},
  volume = {751},
  pages = {L34},
  month = jun,
  eid = {L34},
  adsnote = {Provided by the SAO/NASA Astrophysics Data System},
  archiveprefix = {arXiv},
  doi = {10.1088/2041-8205/751/2/L34},
  eprint = {1205.0394},
  keywords = {stars: early-type, stars: evolution, stars: mass-loss, stars: winds,outflows },
  primaryclass = {astro-ph.SR},
  webpage = {http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2012ApJ...751L..34V}
}
```

And upon compiling I get the error:

```
You can't pop an empty literal stack for entry Dummy2012
```

and the `.bbl` file looks like this:

```
\begin{thebibliography}{1}
\expandafter\ifx\csname natexlab\endcsname\relax\def\natexlab#1{#1}\fi

\bibitem[{{Vink} y {Gr{\"a}fener}(2012)}]{Dummy2012}
{\sc {Vink}, J.~S.} y {\sc {Gr{\"a}fener}, G.}
\newblock {The Transition Mass-loss Rate: Calibrating the Role of Line-driven
  Winds in Massive Star Evolution}.
\newblock {\em APJL\/}, vol. 751, p\'agina L34,
\newblock http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2012ApJ...751L..34V \href{2012}{URL}.

\end{thebibliography}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming that you've also loaded the `hyperref` package. Then, instead of specifying

```
webpage={http://xxx.xxx.xxx...../}
```

you could state

```
webpage={\href{http://xxx.xxx.xxx...../}{URL}}
```

and correspondingly simplify the `format.webpage` and `bbl.availableat` BibTeX functions.

Alternatively, if you don't want to change the content of the `webpage` field, you could rewrite one or both of these BibTeX functions to insert the URL provided by the `webpage` field inside the first argument of the `\href` function and specify `URL` as the second argument of `\href`. Looking at your code, I would guess that (i) you needn't invoke the `bbl.availableat` function at all and (ii) you may want to replace the string

```
" \url{" * swap$ *  "}"
```

in the `format.webpage` function with

```
" \href{" * swap$ *  "}{URL}"
```

Note that I haven't been able to try this out fully because you haven't provided sufficiently many details about your custom `.bst` file.

**Addendum** to follow up on the OP's additional information: Please try the following form of the BibTeX function `format.webpage`:

```
FUNCTION {format.webpage}
{ webpage empty$
    { "" }
    { new.block " \href{" webpage * "}{URL}" * }
  if$
}
```

where the content of the `webpage` field should be a URL, e.g., `http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2012ApJ...751L..34V`. Finally -- and you may already have done so, but I'll mention it for the sake of completeness -- be sure to include in your `format.article` function a line such as

```
format.webpage output
```

Comment: Thanks @Mico, I tried your suggestion but couldn't compile. Please take a look at the new **Edit** in the question. Oh, and I didn't put the `.bst` file because it's pretty big, but if you want to take a look at it, just tell me and I'll post it.

Comment: @Gaba_p: Please see my follow-up comments and suggestions.

Comment: Great! That worked perfectly, thank you so much!